# Moment.js - moment().format() creates invalid date?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

`moment().format()` creates a date that is not valid according to `moment().isValid()`

Here is the example:

```
> moment.version
"2.14.1"
> moment.locale()
"fr"
> moment().format("ll")
"29 juill. 2016"
> moment("29 juill. 2016", "ll", true).isValid()
false
```

However if I remove the period in the month it works:

```
> moment("29 juill 2016", "ll", true).isValid()
true
```

Or if I disable strict parsing (remove the 3rd parameter) it works:

```
> moment("29 juill. 2016", "ll").isValid()
true
```

Why is this? Why doesn't `moment().format("ll")` create a date that is valid with strict parsing?

Comment: please put "moment.locale('de');"

Comment: It still returns false even if I remove the period in the month. https://jsfiddle.net/f0pa2pb1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Answering this myself in case someone else faces the same issue.***

This was due to an issue with `moment.js` version `2.8.1` not parsing custom short month names with periods correctly. This issue is resolved in the later version `2.14.1`.

Here's the example that produces different results in `2.8.1` and `2.14.1`

```
moment.locale("fr", {
  monthsShort: [
    "janv.",
    "févr.",
    "mars",
    "avr.",
    "Mai",
    "juin",
    "juilltest.",
    "août",
    "sept.",
    "oct.",
    "nov.",
    "déc."
  ],
  monthsParseExact: true,
  longDateFormat: {
    LL: "DD MMM YYYY",
    ll: "DD MMM YYYY"
  },

});
console.log(moment.version);
moment.locale('fr');
console.log(moment.locale());
var testDate = '29 juilltest. 2016'; // month name with period in it that matches the custom short name given above
console.log(moment(testDate, "LL", true).isValid());
console.log(moment(testDate, "ll", true).isValid());
console.log(moment.localeData("fr"));
```

**Version 2.8.1:** https://jsfiddle.net/3do4ubsj/

```
2.8.1
fr
false
false
```

**Version 2.14.1:** https://jsfiddle.net/pkhcaqmy/

```
2.14.1
fr
true
true
```

The commit that fixed it: https://github.com/moment/moment/commit/fc5a352e9ca30e32a96875810604ad981d1442c3

A related issue in moment.js repo: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3126

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because `"ll"` is not a valid date formatting, if you will run the moment function and ask for a timestamp (`.valueOf`) you will get a `NaN`

```
moment("29 juill 2016", "ll", true).valueOf()
// NaN
```

You need to provide a valid formatting for the 2nd argument, for your date string it would be `"DD MMMM, YYYY"`

Also, I think you had a typo in `juill`, I think it should be `juillet`

```
moment.locale("fr")
// "fr"
 moment("29 july, 2016", "DD MMMM, YYYY", true).isValid()
// false
 moment("29 juillet, 2016", "DD MMMM, YYYY", true).isValid()
// true
```